# How can i automatically replace two separate ID's in Json object file using java, RestAssured testing web services

Tags: java, json, groovy

I am testing web services using java, RestAssured, groovy notation etc.

I have got separate modules that are depending on each other in terms of passing request methods. such as POST, PUT. when i want to do a POST request on a module, in json schema i have to pass existing id from two different modules into the file. i.e site_id and group_id respectively.

Below is my json schema that i have store in the file:

```
{
"site_id": 10,
"permission": "admin.client.add",
"group_id": 3
}
```

Below is my code: from my page class as am using Page object framework.

```
    public String postpermission(String siteid, String grpid)
    throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ParseException {

    Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(path
            + "/resources/permission/postpermission.json"));
    String d = obj.toString();

    Object objecc = parser.parse(d.replaceFirst("3", grpid));

    Object objec = parser.parse(d.replaceFirst("10", siteid));
    JSONObject jsonPostBody = (JSONObject) objec;

    jsonPostBody = (JSONObject) objecc;

    return postRequest(jsonPostBody, permissionURI, 201, "data.id",
            "postpermission()", false);

    }
```

Below is code from my test class:

```
@Test
public void postpermission() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException,
        ParseException {

    String siteid = sites.postsites();
    String grpid = group.postGroup();
    String permid = permission.postpermission(siteid, grpid);
    permission.deletepermission(permid);

    }
```

Note: with this code i can replace one id but it doesn't replace the second one. Please can anyone provide me with better way to make it work.

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to notice that the `replaceFirst` method will not change the original String, it will return the result as a new String.

So in your case, you need to reassign the first `replaceFirst` result back to variable `d`. The code as below:

```
d = d.replaceFirst("3", grpid);

Object objec = parser.parse(d.replaceFirst("10", siteid));
```

Or you can use simpler one:

```
Object objec = parser.parse(d.replaceFirst("3", grpid).replaceFirst("10", siteid));
```

One more suggestion about the JSON schema (I would like to call it json template) you have, it's better to have placeholders instead of using numbers.e.g.

```
{
"site_id": {site_id},
"permission": "admin.client.add",
"group_id": {group_id}
}
```

Also you may checkout this [JSON template](https://code.google.com/p/json-template/) project if you need do more things on json template.

Comment: Your solution worked fine for me. i couldn't realised that i can extend the replaceFirst method as you did. thanks a lot for your help and time.